# store various menus lists in database according to restaurants in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have data

```
shopname  Items
shop1     rajma rice
shop1     kadi rice
shop2     rajma rice
shop2     kadi rice
```

and so on..

Now I have to work for 100 shops with various items . The structure is as

```
shopid , menuid , itemid , itemname , item price.
```

How it is more normalised?

Answer (score 0):

Simpl can you make one menu table add all menu item in that and connect reference key with show table. when new shop create the all item of shop connect with menu table with perticular item id